# Jstl c:url tag behaves differently on different servers

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, jstl

I have a Java webapp that is packaged in a war file and deployed on a jboss server. The following simple jstl tag is used in one of the jsp's:

```
<c:url value="/someFile.pdf"/>
```

When I browse to `localhost:8080/mywebapp/user/download.do` The jsp is shown and the download button which uses the url links to this path:

```
http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/someFile.pdf
```

I can download the file and everything works.

However, when I deploy this war file on our test server and go to `testserver:8080/mywebapp/user/download.do`, the output of the url tag is the following:

```
http://testserver:8080/mywebapp/user/someFile.pdf
```

This file doesn't download because the is not located in the /user/ subfolder.

My local server is a JBOSS 6.4 embedded in Eclipse that runs in standalone mode. My test server is also a JBOSS 6.4 but it runs on domain mode. The war file is identical on both containers. How can this difference in output of the `<c:url>` tag be explained?

Comment: Are you sbsolutely sure that you're no using `/someFile.pdf` in the first case, and `someFile.pdf`(i.e. without the leading slash) in the second? Because that would explain the difference.

Comment: Yup, it's the same war file (and thus some jsp/source code) in both cases. Btw, where is the fact that a leading slash changes the behaviour of the tag documented?

Comment: In the specifications: *"an implementation must prepend
the context path to a URL that starts with a slash"*. Your war might be identical, but if you use something like `<c:url value="${someUrl}">`, and the value of the variable is not the same (because, for example, the database containing URLs doesn't contain the same values), then it could explain the difference.

Comment: it's hardcoded in the jsp to be <c:url value="/importfile.xls"/> so I assume it's environment independent. Thanks for helping though.